# Java android moshi parse Json to Object

Tags: java, android, json

I use a moshi to parse JSon to Object . This is my JSon :

```
[{
   "id": 4,
   "phone":    {
      "id": 3,
      "imei": "356938035643801",
      "description": "Marek Kowalski"
   },
   "user":    {
      "id": 3,
      "username": "marek.kowalski",
      "first_name": "Marek",
      "last_name": "Kowalski"
   },
   "user_id": 3,
   "message": "Podejrzane zachowanie, sprawdĹş.",
   "date_time_data": "2017-09-05T22:26:44.916927Z",
   "longitude": 19.934113,
   "latitude": 50.075086,
   "confirm": 0,
   "changetime": "2017-09-05T22:26:44.930357Z",
   "has_coordinates": 1
}]
```

This is my Object :

```
public class Message {

    String message;
    double longitude;
    double latitude;
    int confirm;

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

    public double getLongitude() {
        return longitude;
    }

    public void setLongitude(double longitude) {
        this.longitude = longitude;
    }

    public double getLatitude() {
        return latitude;
    }

    public void setLatitude(double latitude) {
        this.latitude = latitude;
    }

    public int getConfirm() {
        return confirm;
    }

    public void setConfirm(int confirm) {
        this.confirm = confirm;
    }
}
```

And I did this to parse JSON to obecjt :

```
 Message message = App.getMsg().fromJson(new String(responseBody, "UTF-8"));
```

But my app is crash and in logs I see this :

> User-space exception detected!
>                                                             com.squareup.moshi.JsonDataException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was
>   BEGIN_ARRAY at path $
>                                                                 at com.squareup.moshi.BufferedSourceJsonReader.beginObject(BufferedSourceJsonReader.java:171)
>                                                                 at com.squareup.moshi.ClassJsonAdapter.fromJson(ClassJsonAdapter.java:145)
>                                                                 at com.squareup.moshi.JsonAdapter$1.fromJson(JsonAdapter.java:68)
>                                                                 at com.squareup.moshi.JsonAdapter.fromJson(JsonAdapter.java:33)
>                                                                 at com.squareup.moshi.JsonAdapter.fromJson(JsonAdapter.java:37)
>                                                                 at jaceknikiel.apk.MsgActivity$1.onSuccess(MsgActivity.java:37)
>                                                                 at com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpResponseHandler.handleMessage(AsyncHttpResponseHandler.java:351)
>                                                                 at com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpResponseHandler$ResponderHandler.handleMessage(AsyncHttpResponseHandler.java:510)
>                                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
>                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6692)
>                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1468)
>                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1358)

Comment: `List<Message> message` instead of `Message message` because you have array of objects

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that you are asking for a `Message` object but you actually have an **array** of `Message` objects. Try doing this:

```
String jsonResponseBody = ...;
Type type = Types.newParameterizedType(List.class, Message.class);
JsonAdapter<List<Message>> adapter = moshi.adapter(type);
List<Message> messages = adapter.fromJson(jsonResponseBody);
```